# Get all subcategories id's ( their subcategories too) from category slug of woocommerce category

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I tried alot to get id of the category whose slug is (music,clothing) and its subcategories and their subcategories too from category slug in sql.

It seems that i m missing something in my sql query.

Here is the Query:

```
  "SELECT ".$wpdb->terms.".term_id FROM ".$wpdb->terms." INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->term_taxonomy." ON ".$wpdb->terms.".term_id = ".$wpdb->term_taxonomy.".term_id WHERE ".$wpdb->term_taxonomy.".parent in (SELECT ".$wpdb->terms.".term_id FROM ".$wpdb->terms." WHERE ".$wpdb->terms.".slug in ('music','clothing'))";
```

It returns me the subcategory id of the category slug (music,clothing) but i need their subcategories id's too if they exist along with the id of category slug (music,clothing).

Can anyone help me out to achieve this.

Comment: Any particular reason you are trying to get this straight from the database instead of using built-in functions?

Comment: All the more reason to use builtin functions. It will likely be faster, especially if you need to repeat the queries (due to internal caching of objects such as categories), less prone to errors and unexpected security flaws (because you let wordpress write the actual query), and *much* more future-proof (the database structure is more likely to change than wordpress functions).... and it's just good practice to use a function if it exists. [get_categories](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) will undoubtedly solve your problem better than any direct DB-query can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query :

```
//Dont forget to change `woo` to your database prefix
SELECT a.term_id, a.name FROM `woo_terms` a INNER JOIN `woo_term_taxonomy` b on a.term_id=b.term_id WHERE b.parent IN (SELECT term_id FROM `woo_terms` WHERE slug IN ('music', 'clothing')) OR a.slug IN ('music', 'clothing')
```

Hope it will help you. Let me know if you have any doubt.